# jquery Toggling between sidebars

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create simple sidebar. I have 2 links, clicking on them expand sidebar with different div>. Clicking again collapse it.
How can I make, that clicking on link2, with expanded sidebar from link1, would change only div and not collapse sidebar? Something like panel in http://www.w3schools.com/ (click Tutorials/References/Examples)

```
#wrapper { padding-left: 0; }
#wrapper.toggled { padding-left: 220px; }
#wrapper-link1 { display:none; }

$('[data-toggle="link1"]').click(function () {
    $('#wrapper').toggleClass('toggled');
    $('#wrapper-link2').hide();
    $('#wrapper-link1').show();
});
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more? Sidebars, are usually on the side, but the panel you're referring to is a vertical dropdown that pushes the other content down when open.

Comment: @SunnyPatel don't get bogged down in minutiae, OP simply wants to toggle content inside another element based on what was click.

Answer (score 0):

What you're attempting to do what is known as tabbed content. In your specific instance the presentation is a little different but the implementation is the same/similar.

What you want to do is bind the same click handler to all links that will show their own content DIV. This handler will then hide the currently shown DIV and show the selected content DIV.

#### HTML

```html
<ul class="sidebar-toggler">
  <li><a href="#" data-target="a">Link A</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-target="b">Link B</a></li>
</ul>

<aside class="sidebar-content">
  <div data-content="a">
    Content for <strong>Link A</strong>.
  </div>
  <div data-content="b">
    Content for <strong>Link B</strong>.
  </div>
</aside>
```

#### CSS

```css
.sidebar-content [data-content] {
  display: none;
}
```

#### JS

```js
var $sidebar_content = $( '.sidebar-content' );

$( '.sidebar-toggler' ).on( 'click', '[data-target]', function ( e ) {

    var target = $( this ).data( 'target' );

    $sidebar_content.find( '[data-content]' ).hide();
    $sidebar_content.find( '[data-content="' + target + '"]' ).show();

} );
```

Demo [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hungerstar/efy1qzo4/1/).

Typically when you want to hide one of these tabbed content regions the simplest thing to do his hide all of them instead of searching for which one is open and then closing it.

```js
$sidebar_content.find( '[data-content]' ).hide();
```

Then open the selected content DIV. You could do this a few different ways but I like to use `data-` attributes. `data-target` points to `data-content` with the same value (which can be anything).

```js
var target = $( this ).data( 'target' );
$sidebar_content.find( '[data-content="' + target + '"]' ).show();
```

*Note:* When using jQuery and the `data` object, jQuery will parse any `data-` attributes and store their values there. That's where `data( 'target' )` comes from. See [jQuery.data()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/) for more details.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I'll look for your changing divs implementation. But it isn't what exactly I wanted. I asked mostly about $('#wrapper').toggleClass('toggled'); line. My code render panel outside of view, and when toggled moved it inside. It works nice when clicking on 1 link (open/close), but I want to change it, so when i click on link2 it would not close panel. Sorry for my bad english, look here for my code: https://jsfiddle.net/zodpb7az/2/ Notice how when I click on Link2 with opened sidebar it simple close it.

Comment: What I posted is what you need. You're not using `toggleClass()` properly but that's not the only thing that needs fixing. You should reduce code duplication and improve your markup. What I have posted is an implementation which will prevent you from having to duplicate your code. Here's an [updated example](https://jsfiddle.net/hungerstar/zodpb7az/4/) that is doing the same as above but with markup/layout that is closer to what you're doing. Here's an [updated version](https://jsfiddle.net/hungerstar/efy1qzo4/2/) of my previous example to show that it really is the same thing.